# Going through files recursively and receiving file information

Tags: linux, bash

i am fairly new to bash scripts and right now i am trying to go through files recursively in order to recieve some info about these files (name, size, ...)

My attempt so far:

```
for i in *.txt; do
    stat -c '%n' "$i" >> $2
    wc -l -w >> $2
    stat -c '%a %A %U' "$i" >> $2
done

$2 is the file, where i want to log this info...
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** I should post the problem aswell, sorry

i am receiving this error message:

```
stat: cannot stat '*.txt': No such file or directory
```

But the file should be in the $i variable, shouldnt it?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Edited the problem

Comment: That suggests that you have `for i in '*.txt'; do` which would **iterate** over one file with the literal name `*.txt` (which probably indeed doesn't exist).

Comment: It can also mean that there are no `txt` files in your directory. You can use `shopt -s nullglob` so that the `for` loop doesn't iterate with the literal `*.txt` or check with `[[ -f $i ]]`.

Comment: Why do you put a semi-colon behind `*.txt`? Is it possible this is messing up your loop?

Comment: Don't forget to put `$i` behind the `wc` command :-)

Comment: @Dominique The semi-colon is actually mandatory here. There are some exceptions, such as iterating over positional parameters `for arg do echo "$arg"; done` or the undocumented `for((i=0;i<10;i++)) do echo "$i"; done`.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no files matching the glob, Bash will by default return just the glob itself. So you are trying to process a file named literally "*.txt" (which by the way is actually a valid file name). What you probably want is `shopt -s nullglob` to expand a non-matching glob to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The goto tool for recursive file operations is `find` - it is very powerful, so go make  a cup of tea, settle back and type `man find`